# Calculating 2 or 4 new marginal bounding boxes from 2 overlapping bounding boxes in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, extents, optimization, differences

### The Scenario

I have a web map that calls for data whenever the map moves.  It sends the bounds of the map and returns data within those bounds.  Our data source just got way bigger, so I am trying to reduce the demands on both server and client to transfer data.  The frontend code is set up such that requesting sections of the map that I already requested is redundant.  I want to implement an algorithm to avoid requesting data for the same sections of the map twice.

Imagine the user's viewport is the grey square below.  We call to fetch the data in those bounds. Then the user pans so that their view is the blue square.  We call to get data for those bounds.  The data that lies in the overlap is redundant - its already stored in the front end.  And that data may weigh up to 20 megabytes.  If the user pans and zooms frequently, this is bad for performance.

[image]

### Most efficient solution (maybe?)

My initial thoughts would be to turn the "new area", the backwarwds L shape on the bottom right, into 2 rectangles, and call the api twice with those smaller bounds (or get BE team to accept an array of bounds).  That would mean I'm calling to get data only in "new" territory.  However, this gets messy.  After a few pans and zooms, we may get some crazy shapes. Below is a record of a few pans and zooms, and then one final zoom-out.  In the following image, imagine that I'd already called for everything in a grey box.  How could I calculate the bounds that comprise the space between the outermost grey boxes, and the outer blue bounds?

[image]

You can play with that live [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/accumulated-bounds-testing-eqp9oc).

### Less efficient but better solution

A simpler compromise would be to simply take the sum of the current bounds and the last bounds, and then break the resulting "L" shape into 2 bounds.  For example, on every pan/zoom, I combine the new bounds with the previous one.  That looks like this:

[image]

In this case, imagine the L shape created by the difference between the yellow and grey bounds.  It contains the new area I need to call for data for, as well as some extra squares in the corners.  While that's calling for a little extra data, it also simplifies the problem in that on every subsequent pan / zoom, all I need to do is calculate 2 bounds from the resultant "L" shape, as the previously fetched area will now always be a simple rectangular bounds.

My issue is: **How can I calculate the 2 bounds objects that comprise the L shape that is difference between the new bounds, and the combined old-new bounds?**  Considering I don't know which way the user is panning, or if their current lat/lng value are positive/negative, there seems to be a lot of variation in the manual math I'd need to do.  I've looked into various leaflet/turfjs plugins (i.e. [leaflet-clipper](https://github.com/willfarrell/Leaflet.Clipper), [@turf/difference](https://turfjs.org/docs/#difference), etc), but there doesn't seem to be a clear path.

Additionally, if the user simply zooms out, we get a square with a cutout in the center, i.e. the space between the yellow and grey squares here:

[image]

How can I transform this empty square shape into 4 non-overlapping bounds?

Comment: I'd drop the bounding boxes altogether and implement a grid of square tiles, with the usual pyramids. Then use `L.GridLayer` or `L.TileLayer` or the like.

Comment: @IvanSanchez sorry I'm not sure I understand what you're getting at...can you elaborate?

Comment: "Less efficient but better solution" has two problems. One problem is the case when new view overlaps sum of current bounds only in small part, like 10%. Then using this algorithm would actually require more data transfer that just for the new view. The second problem is when the new view does not overlap the sum of current bounds at all. Then new sum of current bound would have a hole.

Comment: @TomazicM I realize that if the new bounds doesn't overlap the old one at all, this question doesn't make sense.  I'll have to find another solution for that, i.e. keep track of unique, non-overlapping bounds, and perform the algorithm on each one.  Your first point is valid...I wonder what an average user's actual behavior is when panning and zooming an area of interest.  If may be worth calling for "too much data" if after a few pans and zooms, all the data is fetched and no more fetches are required.